# jQuery template not loading when I use change method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to make a web app using jQuery mobile and jQuery tmpl framework.

I want to load the second page and apply a template but the appendTo method doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="ui-block-a" >
    <a href="#" data-transition="slide" id="organiser">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a homepage-block homepage-block-purple">
            <div>
                <img src="../img/organiser.png" width="30px" height="30px">
            </div>
            <div class="homepage-block-text">
                <span style="font-size:30px;">10</span></br>
                Organiser
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on("click", '#organiser', function() {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer(
        "change",
        "organiser.html",
        {
            //reload : true,
            transition: "slide",
        }
    );

    var data = getData(1019386);
    $("ul.myclass").empty();
    $.tmpl(templateList, data).appendTo($("ul.myclass"));
})
```

I am new to jQuery and I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Does "$.tmpl(templateList, data)" return a valid jQuery object?

Comment: Yes I checked and It does

Comment: Cool... so what data do you want to get out of that object to append to the ul.myclass selector? Can you also provide markup for ul.myclass

Comment: Well, the variable templateList is a markup of <li>{{ data }}</li>. When I use the same template with the same data on the same page, it's working perfectly but when I change the page to #organiser, the appendTo method doesn't work

Comment: I think I'm following... will add an answer

Comment: Actually, the $.tmpl(templateList, data) return a PrevObject, when it is working the object contain the li element.  Why in the case of the page change, the object is different ?

Comment: That would imply that the DOM has no knowledge of "ul.myclass" when being called, is that HTML markup on the organiser page?

Comment: What value do you get if you call $("ul.myclass").length while on the organiser page?

Comment: ok, so do i need to wait until the second page is loaded into the DOM to call the template function ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: It sounds like that could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

See comments above, and yes try the following...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#organiser').on('click', function(){

        $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer(
            "change",
            "organiser.html",
            {
                //reload : true,
                transition: "slide",
            }
        );

        var data = getData(1019386);
        var myClass = $('ul.myclass');
        myClass.empty();

        var tmpl = $.tmpl(templateList, data); // $.tmpl(templateList, data).someProperty()
        myClass.append(tmpl);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, now I have a jQuery object with the li element but the append method still does not work, I don't have the li element in the html source code.

Comment: Im not sure then mate?